# perl match some char but not include someone

Tags: regex, perl

I have some string patterns like the following

```
(group 1)[(group 2)]
```

group 1 would be mixed chars of following

(1)  include a-zA-Z but not BCD

(2)  include \s but not \t

How can I use regex for group1 ?

like this ? ([a-zA-Z|^BCD]+|[\s|^\t]+)

Actually, what I want to do is

```
John [….]
John [….]
John [….]
Jahn [….]
Jaja [….]
laja [….]
…
```

I want to use a **regex method** to include John and exclude Jahn, Jaja, laja.

That's to include some specific patterns and exclude some specific patterns in one regex declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in current Perl regex to modify a character class; if you want to exclude something from a character class, you just have to enumerate the characters you want.

`[a-zA-Z]` minus `[BCD]` is `[a-zAE-Z]`.

`\s` minus `\t` is `[\n\f\r ]` (also somewhat depending on flags etc; see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html)

Comment: The Python third-party [`regex` library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) has something called nested sets.